# How do you diagram a sentence that has a nominal phrase that is described by an adjective using the Reed-Kellogg system?

Tags: compounds, diagramming

I have the following sentence:

> I hope everyone had a nice holiday weekend.

My understanding is that "holiday weekend" is a <strike>compound noun</strike> nominal phrase, since it would be incorrect to say "a nice and holiday weekend," or "a holiday nice weekend." "Nice" is specifying what kind of "holiday weekend" it was.

But how would you diagram this sentence using the Reed-Kellogg system? I believe that this is how you would diagram the sentence *without* the nominal phrase:

> I hope everyone had a nice weekend.

[image]

but I'm at a loss as to how you would diagram it with the nominal phrase, and I can't seem to find any examples.

Comment: "Nice" modifies "holiday weekend".

Comment: Right. So would "holiday weekend" just be together on the horizontal line to the right of "had"?

Comment: Depends on the "rules" of diagramming that you follow.

Comment: No: "holiday weekend" is not a compound noun, but a syntactic construction -- a nominal with "weekend" as head and the noun "holiday" as modifier. "Nice" then modifies the nominal "holiday weekend". Incidentally, why are you using the dreadful Reed-Kellogg system of diagramming? It has been intellectually bankrupt for over 100 years, and (to the best of my knowledge) has never been used in the UK.

Comment: Your example has stacked modification, where there are two layers of modification. First, _weekend_ is modified by _holiday_ to form the nominal _holiday weekend_ and this is in turn modified by _nice_ to give "holiday that is nice by the standards normally expected of holiday weekends".

Comment: @BillJ I actually wasn't aware that there was more than one system of diagramming. Apparently Reed-Kellogg just happened to be what I was taught in school (I'm in the United States), and all of the examples I found while searching for an answer to this question appeared to be Reed-Kellogg as well.

Do you know how the given sentence with the nominal "holiday weekend" would be diagrammed using Reed-Kellogg? And how would the sentence be diagrammed in a "better" system?

Comment: Reed-Kellogg has never been used for actual syntactic analysis. It's a baby system that's only useful for simple sentences, as you have discovered. Once you get beyond a single clause, you start to use a lot of paper, and you stop making things clear. For that reason, it's never been used generally in schools (it's totally useless outside of schools), though some teachers have attempted to teach it in some places at some times, with varying degrees of success in transmission. As a result, nobody knows how to do anything with it. But, who knows? Maybe the horse will sing.

Comment: @plexi I entirely agree with JL. If you really must use your Reed-Kellogg diagram, the best you can do is add the modifier "holiday" to the same line as "nice". But I wouldn't put money on it"!  If I get time later, I'll put up a 'conventional' diagram.

Comment: I've added a tree diagram to my answer, which you may find helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I hope everyone had a nice holiday weekend.*

"Holiday weekend" is not a compound noun, but a syntactic construction: a nominal with "weekend" as head and the noun "holiday" as modifier. "Nice" then modifies the nominal "holiday weekend" to give the meaning "holiday that is nice by the standards normally expected of holiday weekends".

Incidentally, the Reed-Kellogg system of diagramming has been intellectually bankrupt for over 100 years, and (to the best of my knowledge) has never been used in the UK. The diagram fails to show the syntactic structure and the function of each constituent.

If you really must use the Reed-Kellogg diagram, the best you can do is add the modifier "holiday" to the same line as "nice".

Edit: Below is more conventional tree diagram, from which it is clear that "nice" modifies the nominal "holiday weekend".

[image]

Comment: This answer, especially combined with @JohnLawler 's comment, addresses the letter of the question (the answer apparently being "you can't really due to the limitations of the system") as well as helpfully challenging the framing of the question (why would anyone want to use the Reed-Kellogg system to diagram sentences in the first place?) Thanks for all the input!